# Excel to Web Automation

Tags: vbscript, automation

Here is what I am trying to do via Macro Automation->

-> I am trying to open the website [url]http://www.metaboanalyst.ca/MetaboAnalyst/faces/Home.jsp[/url]

-> Then clicking on the "click here to start"

-> Then checking the radio button for "Peak intensity table"

-> Then click on "Browse" the data file and select a file ([File that needs to be selected](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?56pnxhb7aj9m5az)) manually.

-> Then finally click on the submit button (which is not working and path to the file vanishes while clicking on the submit button and giving me an Automation error ['-2147352319 (80020101)'])

Here is the code that works fine except for the last step which is submitting->

```
Sub MetaboAnn()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "http://www.metaboanalyst.ca/MetaboAnalyst/faces/Home.jsp"
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
'MsgBox "Done"
IE.Visible = True

IE.Document.getElementById("form1:groupPanel1:loginLink").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
'MsgBox "Done"
IE.Visible = True

IE.Document.getElementById("form1:tabSet1:tab1:layoutPanel7:csvButtonGroup:csvButtonGroup_2_rb").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
'MsgBox "Done"
IE.Visible = True

IE.Document.all("form1:tabSet1:tab1:layoutPanel7:statCsvUpload_com.sun.webui.jsf.upload").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
'MsgBox "Done"
IE.Visible = True

IE.Document.getElementById("form1:tabSet1:tab1:layoutPanel7:csvSubmitButton").Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE, try to click on TOOLS, then COMPATIBILY VIEW SETTINGS and add the website you're on.  It probably has something to do with older code on that website.